# Disable / hide button depending on checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

Is there a way to disable or hide a  if the  is checked ?

I would like to make `CreateQuotation` & `TakeNotes` buttons to hide or disable when the checkbox is not checked

Heres how my code looks like

```
const renderCheckbox = ({ input, label }) =>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Checkbox
        {...input}
        checked={input.value ? true : false}
        onCheck={input.onChange}
      />
    }
    label={label}
  />

const CreateReport = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = props;

  return (
    <div className="create-report-form-container mobile-padding">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <Field name="quotation-checkbox" component={renderCheckbox} label="Quotation to do" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <Button raised color="accent" label="CreateQuotation">
            Create a Quotation
          </Button>
          <Button raised color="accent" label="TakeNotes">
            Take some notes
          </Button>
        </div>


        <Button raised color="accent" type="submit" label="send" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Send
        </Button>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'CreateReport',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(CreateReport);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a constant variable like isActive which is toggling the checkbox state and to show and hide the Button you can do this in the return area:

```
{ isActive ? <Button>create Quotation & Take notes </Button> : null }
```

You can get the isActive state with calling a function in the state change:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   onChange={(event) => this.handleCheck(event)}
   checked={true}
/>

constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isActive: {}
      };
      this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
    }

handleCheck(event){
      isActive = event.target.checked;
      this.setState({ isActive: isActive });
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to react and front-end dev. You mean doing a isActive const then passing it as props to renderCheckBox to use it on a onChange event ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rq extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      option: '',
      isDisabled: true,
      checked: true    
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(){
this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
  if (this.state.checked) 
  {
    this.setState({isDisabled: false})

  }
else

  this.setState({isDisabled: true});
}


handleSubmit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if (this.state.isDisabled===false) {
  alert('Form submitted')

 } else
 {
  alert('form has not submitted');
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about the important parts of your code?

Comment: In the above code i just write as per My Requirement... When user want to enable Submit button only after checkbox is Checked... Then only the submit button will Enable.... If any queries please mention.. Thnks in advance

Comment: Please add such explanations to the code itself, in form of comments. As there is already an accepted answer which is nearly a year old, you could highlight what makes the difference between your answer and the existing one, so that people can learn from that difference